# Plotting a time series with distinctive events

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm new to data viz. and was wondering what the simplest way is to plot my data:

I have a pd.dataframe that looks like:

```
df.head()
    price     event
1   123
2   456       A
3   789
...
```

I would like to have a time series just as if I did

```
df.plot(x='price')
```

But with events visible on the plot at for each entry in my DataFrame where my 'event' column is equal to something.

What are my best options?

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of plot? do you have a preference?

Comment: Something like this [link] (https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat510/sites/onlinecourses.science.psu.edu.stat510/files/L01/graph_01/index.gif) but with the name (as a string) for each red dot on the graph equal to my column 'event'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took the liberty and added one more row with event z.

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
x = df.reset_index()['index']
y = df['price']
ax.scatter(x, y)
ax.plot(y)
for i, txt in enumerate(df['event']):
    ax.annotate(txt, (x[i]+0.1,y[i]))
```

Output:

[image]